# Template Specialization of Template method

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, template-specialization

OK I have:

```
template<typename T>
class Reader
{
    class Input
    {
        template<typename C>
        void operator()(C& val) const
        {
            /* Do Some Work */
        }
    };
};
```

Unfortunately the generic version of "Do Some Work" does not work for me. Nor it is easy to modify because it is in the middle of some heavy template meta programming code.

So I though I could specialize the method for my type. So my first step was to try and pull the general method out of the class.

```
template<typename T>
class Reader
{
    class Input
    {
        template<typename C>
        void operator()(C& val) const;
    };
};


template<typename T>
template<typename C>
void typename Reader<T>::Input template operator()<C>(C& val) const   // LINE 13
{
    /* Do Some Work */
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the error:

> s.h:13: error: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write it like normal

```
template<typename T>
template<typename C>
void Reader<T>::Input::operator()(C& val) const   // LINE 13
{
    /* Do Some Work */
}
```

Defining the generic version out of class doesn't help you with providing special versions of it though, or I do miss the goal of yours here.

Comment: Input isn't a template class.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct I can't specialize the method. Working on another tack for a second. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is impossible as it counts as partial function template specialization, which is not allowed. `void Reader<T>::Input::operator () (C& int)` has an implicit first argument (the `this` pointer) of type `Reader<T>::Input *`, hence its signature is in fact `void (Reader<T>::Input *, C &)`. You are trying to specify `C`, yet not `T`.